# The blade of the leaf

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme, limerick

> Given a bird, a cat and a shrew,
>
> along with a bat to give you a few.
>
> Some sleep at night,
>
> others in light,
>
> surprisingly you are one too.

How do *you* relate to the title?

Comment: rot 13 (Fbzr fyrrc va avtug fbhaqf yvxr hf, bgure va yvtug ner abpgheany...)

Comment: rot 13 (uzzz Gur oynqr bs gur yrns vf n ynzvan, naq n tbbtyr qrsvavgvba frnepu gryyf zr gung vg vf  n fpnyr bs frqvzragnel ebpx... znlor gungf jul gur gvgyr jnf gung svefg. Abj v'z fghpx gubhtu.)

Comment: @Stevo if you’ve solved the limerick, think of how it’s answer relates to what you just stated.

Comment: The problem is that i haven't solvd the limerick... yet. (I might have, i just dont know yet)

Comment: I think I got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to have a guess at it:

> Animal

Why?

Given a bird, cat, and a shrew, along with a bat to give you a few

> Firstly, we see that cats, shrews, bats, and birds are all animals.

Some sleep at night, others in light

> Animals are either nocturnal or diurnal.

The title:

> It leads us to lamina, the blade of a leaf.

Surprisingly, you are one too

> We are animals!

And,

> See how birds, cats, shrews, bats, and birds are all animal(s).   Reverse lamina, and you get animal!